# Run function on VB.NET, leave page, then have it email result to user?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an admin function that's rarely used that is built in VB.NET. It prepares a very long and complicated document and takes a very long time to process after user has hit the "Export PDF" button. What I would like to do is have ability for user to hit the Export button, leave the page and have it still going in the background and then when it's done, email the user to let them know report is ready with the URL of the file it generated.

I'm unsure if this is possible. It's my understanding that if you leave a page before a process is finished, it will interrupt/cancel the process. I can't reprogram my function in another language because it's just too complex for me to attempt to do that, so I need to stick with VB.NET.

I realize that it's not good practice to have a function that takes a long time on the server, but as I said, this is rarely used by a select amount of users and I'd like to make it more convenient for them.

Anyone know the best method/if any to get this accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Spawn a new thread and perform the task in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you can do one of these:

1. Create a child thread (spawn) and let that thread create and email PDF
2. Create a service and call that service to create and email PDF